# How do I call posts with a certain tag?

Tags: categories, query-posts, archives

I use this to call posts:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$per_page = get_option('to_count_archives');
query_posts("posts_per_page=".$per_page."&paged=".$paged."&cat=".$cat);
if (have_posts())
?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

And it works great for categories.  But **on archives pages generated for tags it shows ALL posts, not just posts with a specific tag**.  I am going to creates a separate archives.php and category.php.

I need to keep the to_count_archives part of the code because it calls the number of posts per page.

I appreciate any help rewriting the code above to work correctly.

Comment: Does this help? http://codex.wordpress.org/Tag_Templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you call `query_posts`, you're overwriting the original query with a new one, you have to get the original query and reset the things you want to change.

```
global $query_string;
$per_page = get_option( 'to_count_archives' );
query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=' . $per_page );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and do something like:

```
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query(  array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'tag' => 'THETAG' ) );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;
```

You could also do the same thing for category. I hope I understood the question your code sample above confused me. I just find WP_Query easier to use :)